# I has received procedure too large error in access vba code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I received below error message:

> Procedure too large

I think VBA has a limit of 64k or something per procedure.  How can I split this code, or shorten it?

```
If txt29.Value = "" Then
    Box67.BackColor = labelnull.BackColor
    cmd29.Enabled = False
Else
    cmd29.Enabled = True
End If

If txt29.Value = "Yellow" Then
    Box67.BackColor = LabelYellow.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Blue" Then
    Box67.BackColor = LabelBlue.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Red" Then
    Box67.BackColor = LabelRed.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Brown" Then
    Box67.BackColor = lableBrown.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Pink" Then
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "White" Then
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Grey" Then
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Purple" Then
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
End If

If txt29.Value = "Green" Then
    Box67.BackColor = LabelGreen.BackColor
End If
```

I need to do the same as above for 100 buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Select Case as well to shorten the code:

```
If txt29.Value = "" Then
  Box67.BackColor = labelnull.BackColor
  cmd29.Enabled = False
Else
  cmd29.Enabled = True
End If

Select Case txt29.value
  Case  "Yellow"
    Box67.BackColor = LabelYellow.BackColor
  Case "Blue" 
    Box67.BackColor = LabelBlue.BackColor
  Case "Red"
    Box67.BackColor = LabelRed.BackColor
  Case "Brown"
    Box67.BackColor = lableBrown.BackColor
  Case "Pink"
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
  Case "White"
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
  Case "Grey"
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
  Case "Purple"
    Box67.BackColor = Labelpink.BackColor
  Case "Green"
    Box67.BackColor = LabelGreen.BackColor
End Select
```

This will also speed it up as it won't have to run through every option if the value happens to be "Yellow"

Answer (score 0):

You could create 10 functions each setting 10 controls.

Then call these ten functions from one "master" function.

Comment: Thanks you lots for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say just reference the label with the correct name and look at the back colour of it - it won't work for the Pink labels though:

```
If IsNull(txt29.Value) Then
    box67.BackColor = labelnull.BackColor
Else
    box67.BackColor = Me.Controls("Label" & txt29.Value).BackColor
End If
```

It'll also cause problems if the code tries to reference a label that doesn't exist.